# error in using request object in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session

I am creating a method in jsp to deal with database and I want to use request object to get session object. But eclipse is displaying an error saying,

> request can not be resolved.

Here is the code of my method:

```
public void getTest()
{
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    String username=session.getAttribute("email");
}
```